# xml issue after upgrade android studio to 4.2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

after upgrade when generating anything vector assets or add an attribute with a number, the number value goes with the wrong format.
Arabic instead of English
example ١٠dp not 10dp

```
      android:pathData="M١٠,٦.٦٦٦٧V١٠L١٢.٥,١٢.٥M١٧.٥,١٠C١٧.٥,١٤.١٤٢١ ١٤.١٤٢١,١٧.٥ ١٠,١٧.٥C٥.٨٥٧٩,١٧.٥ ٢.٥,١٤.١٤٢١ ٢.٥,١٠C٢.٥,٥.٨٥٧٩ ٥.٨٥٧٩,٢.٥ ١٠,٢.٥C١٤.١٤٢١,٢.٥ ١٧.٥,٥.٨٥٧٩ ١٧.٥,١٠Z"

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="١٦dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="٠dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Two ways will help you to solve this.

1. Open project root directory

   .gradle and .idea folders
   In the android studio, Open Files Menu -> Innvallid Cache and restart
2. List item

   Go to Build menu -> Clean Project
   then Rebuild Project

Comment: did you try to downgrade the android studio?